# Add different colors in circle android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, geometry

I have created a circle in custom view. I want to add 6 colors to it based on a condition. The 6 regions will keep changing based on the condition.  For eg, each region can vary from 30 degrees to 90 degrees to 120 degrees. 
My question is
1) How do I add 6 colors to the circle. Please note that I cannot divide the circle into 6 equal regions, thats not how it is supposed to be.
2) How do I assign the starting and ending points of the regions. For example if I want to add green color from 45degrees to 90 degrees. How do I do this?
The end product is supposed to look as below

```
package com.example.submission_customclock;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteView;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * This widget display an analogic clock with two hands for hours and
 * minutes.
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#AnalogClock_dial
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#AnalogClock_hand_hour
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#AnalogClock_hand_minute
 */

@RemoteView
public class AnalogClock extends View {
    private Time mCalendar;
    private static final String DEBUGTAG = "FA";
    private Drawable mHourHand;
    private Drawable mMinuteHand;
    private Drawable mSecondHand;
    private Drawable mDial;
    private Drawable mDial_frame;
    private Drawable mDial_center;

    private int mDialWidth;
    private int mDialHeight;

    private boolean mAttached;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private float mMinutes;
    private float mHour;
    private boolean mChanged;

    public AnalogClock(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    Context mContext;
    public AnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                       int defStyle) {  
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        mContext=context;
        Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Analog clock started");


       mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock4);
       mDial_frame = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_frame);
       mDial_center = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_dot);
       mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hour_hand);
       mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.minute_hand);
       mSecondHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.second_hand);

        mCalendar = new Time();

        mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();    
        mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (!mAttached) {
            mAttached = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

            getContext().registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);
        }

        // NOTE: It's safe to do these after registering the receiver since the receiver always runs
        // in the main thread, therefore the receiver can't run before this method returns.

        // The time zone may have changed while the receiver wasn't registered, so update the Time
        mCalendar = new Time();

        // Make sure we update to the current time
        onTimeChanged();
        counter.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mAttached) {
            counter.cancel();
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
            mAttached = false;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        float hScale = 1.0f;
        float vScale = 1.0f;

        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && widthSize < mDialWidth) {
            hScale = (float) widthSize / (float) mDialWidth;
        }

        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightSize < mDialHeight) {
            vScale = (float )heightSize / (float) mDialHeight;
        }

        float scale = Math.min(hScale, vScale);
        Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"onMeasure params: " + widthSize + " " 
                + heightSize + " " + hScale + " " + vScale + " " + scale); 

        try {
            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState((int) (mDialWidth * scale), widthMeasureSpec, 0),
                   resolveSizeAndState((int) (mDialHeight * scale), heightMeasureSpec, 0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mChanged = true;
    }

    boolean mSeconds=false;
    float mSecond=0;
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        boolean changed = mChanged;
        if (changed) {
            mChanged = false;
        }

        boolean seconds = mSeconds;
        if (seconds ) {
            mSeconds = false;
        }
        int availableWidth = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        int availableHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();

        int x = availableWidth / 2;
        int y = availableHeight / 2;

        final Drawable dial = mDial;
        final Drawable dial_frame = mDial_frame;
        final Drawable dial_dot = mDial_center;
        int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();
        boolean scaled = false;
      //  Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"onDraw params: " + availableWidth +" "+  availableHeight + " " +
        //      x + " " + y + " " + w + " "+ h + " " + changed);

        if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
            scaled = true;
            //float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,
              //                     (float) availableHeight / (float) h);
            canvas.save();
            float scale1 = (float) 0.6;
            float scale2 = (float) 0.8;

          //  Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"scale params: " + scale1 + " " + scale2);
            canvas.scale(scale1, scale2, x, y);
        }

        if (changed) {
            //Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Bounds params: " + (x - (w / 2)) + " " + (y - (h / 2)) + " " + ( x + (w / 2)) + " " + (y + (h / 2)));
            dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
            //dial_frame.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
            //Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Bounds params: " + (x - (w / 2 + w/10)) + " " + (y - (h / 2 + h/10)) + " " + ( x + (w / 2 + w/10)) + " " + 
              //         (y + (h / 2 + h/10)));
            dial_frame.setBounds(x - (w/2 + w/10), y - (h/2 + h/10), x + (w/2 + w/10), y + (h/2 + h/10));
           dial_dot.setBounds(x -30 , y -20 , x + 30, y + 20);
          //Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Bounds params: " + (x ) + " " + (y) + " " + ( x + (w / 2 )) + " " + 
            //         (y + (h / 2)));
        }
        int radius = 0;
        if(x>y)
            radius=y-10;
        else
            radius=x-10;
        Paint circlepaint;
        circlepaint = new Paint();
        circlepaint.
        dial.draw(canvas);
        dial_frame.draw(canvas);

       // canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, circlepaint);      

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 180.0f, x - 10, y - 10);
        final Drawable hourHand = mHourHand;
        if (changed) {
            w = hourHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = hourHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            hourHand.setBounds(x -w/2, y - h/2 - h/4 , x + w/6, y + h/6);
        }
        hourHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, x - 10, y - 10);

        final Drawable minuteHand = mMinuteHand;
        if (changed) {
            w = minuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = minuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            //minuteHand.setBounds(x, y, x + (w / 2 + w/10), y + (h / 2 + w/10));
            minuteHand.setBounds(x - w, y - h/2, x + w/6, y + h/6);
         //   Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Bounds params:x " + (x) + " y " + (y) + " w " + ( w ) + " h " + 
           //         (h));
           // Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Bounds params: " + (x - w) + " " + (y - h/2) + " " + ( x ) + " " + 
             //       (y));
        }
        minuteHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mSecond, x, y);

        if (seconds) {
            w = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
          //  mSecondHand.setBounds(x, y, x + (w / 2 + w/10), y + (h / 2 + w/10));
            mSecondHand.setBounds(x-w/6, y-h/6, x + w,y + h/2);
            Log.d(AnalogClock.DEBUGTAG,"Bounds params: " + (x ) + " " + (y) + " " + ( w) + " " + 
                    (h));
        }
        mSecondHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        dial_dot.draw(canvas);

        if (scaled) {
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
    MyCount counter = new MyCount(10000, 1000);

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counter.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mCalendar.setToNow();

            int second = mCalendar.second;

              mSecond=6.0f*second;
            mSeconds=true;
             //mChanged = true;
             AnalogClock.this.invalidate();
         }
     }

    private void onTimeChanged() {
        mCalendar.setToNow();

        int hour = mCalendar.hour;
        int minute = mCalendar.minute;
        int second = mCalendar.second;

        mMinutes = minute + second / 60.0f;
        mHour = hour + mMinutes / 60.0f;
        mChanged = true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
                String tz = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone");
                mCalendar = new Time(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz).getID());
            }

            onTimeChanged();

            invalidate();
        }
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use the `drawArc` method of the `Canvas` class. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF, float, float, boolean, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. This works perfectly. Can you also suggest how do I add text inside the arc as in the above screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure but you might like to try looking at the `setRotation` methods of the `View` class. If you create `TextView` widgets dynamically and set their rotation and layout position correctly it should work but I've never tried it.